# VSCode not changing double quotes to single quotes in <template> when using Vetur and Prettier and Vue-Cli 3

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-cli-3, prettier

I am trying to set up my VSCode editor to autoformat my Vuejs code. I am using the Vetur extension, the [Prettier extension](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode), and the [ESLint extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint).

**The problem is that when I save my `.vue` files, the single quotes are automatically changed to double quotes in my `<template>` elements:**

When I write code like so and then save...

```
<template>
    <section>
        <section v-if='errored'>
        ...snip...
</template>
```

VSCode automatically changes the single quotes to double quotes in the .vue `template` section like so:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <section v-if="errored"> <-------- 
        ...snip...
</template>
```

And then I get warnings and errors for the rest of the `<template>` code. However, the code in the `<script>` and `<style>` sections of the `.vue` single file components are left intact/and/or fixed correctly....it's just the `<template>` section that has the above issue. So, do I have my settings correct?

My settings are:

I set my Prettier config file in project root **`.prettierrc.js`** like so:

```
module.exports = {
    singleQuote: true
};
```

My **`.eslintrc.js`** looks like so:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    '@vue/prettier'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': 'off',
    'no-debugger': 'off'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
};
```

And then in my **VSCode user settings** I have:

```
...snip..
"vetur.validation.template": false, <-- turn off Vetur’s linting feature and rely on ESLint + Prettier, instead
  "eslint.validate": [
    {
      "language": "vue",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "html",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "javascript",
      "autoFix": true
    }
  ],
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
```

And the app's **`package.json`** file contains the following devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a file named `.prettierrc.js` in the directory I run npm `run serve in`.

This file contains:

```
module.exports = {
    singleQuote: true,
    trailingComma: "es5",
    printWidth: 200
};
```

Now it mostly works, except for method calls that are longer then 200. Then pretier forgets a comma at the end.

Comment: trailingComma does not work. Just very brutely changed  trailingComma: "es5", to trailingComma: false, . And you know what it worked. Don't have a slightest idea if I had done correctly but it did worked.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I found to get this to work was to remove the following from my `.eslintrc.js`

```
'plugin:prettier/recommended',
'@vue/prettier'
```

Comment: dxmn... This works for me, too. None of other solutions work. Still, I cannot figure out what's wrong under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default formatter from prettier to vetur worked for me